# Gather dict from another dict in Ansible

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible

I have some dict:

```
users_to_add:
    - username: Harley Quinn
      login: 90987264
      group: mininform
      group_desc: "Some random data for description"
      personal_data:
        - first_name: Harley
          last_name: Quinn
          mail: harley@gmail.com
          telnum: +7777777777
          jobtitle: minister
    - username: Vasya Pupkin
      login: 77777777
      group: mininform
      group_desc: "Some random data for description"
      personal_data:
        - first_name: Vasya
          last_name: Pupkin
          mail: vasya@gmail.com
          telnum: +7970000000
          jobtitle: minister
```

And i have ansible module that works only with lists:

```
- name: Create needed groups
    ipa_group:
      state: present
      name: "{{ item.group }}"
      description: "{{ item.group_desc }}"
      ipa_host: "{{ global_host }}"
      ipa_user: "{{ global_user }}"
      ipa_pass: "{{ global_pass }}"
      validate_certs: no
      user: []
    with_items:
      - "{{ users_to_add }}"
```

This module wants list of users under "user" argument, creating a group and adding users to it. I want to map the dict "users_to_add" like this:
(using users_to_add dict)
`{group_name: ["user1", "user2"...]}` and feed this new dict to the module.
How can I accomplish this with `ansible`?
I know that first i should use

```
set_fact:
    new_dict: 
with_items: {{ users_to_add }}
```

...

And then feed this new dict to the module, where key is group name to create and value - list of users to add to group, but i can't understand how to accomplish this with `ansible`...

Comment: It's hard to understand what do you want to achieve here... `ipa_group` module creates groups and assign users to them. But you iterate over `users_to_add` and not groups. Please edit your question with exactly what group names do you want to be created containing which user names.

Comment: I want to iterate users_to_add dict and gather all group names and user logins in new dict, where: {group: [all users that have this group], group: ...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  - name: Create needed groups
    ipa_group:
      state: present
      name: "{{ item }}"
      description: "{{ users_to_add | selectattr('group','equalto',item) | map(attribute='group_desc') | list | first }}"
      ipa_host: "{{ global_host }}"
      ipa_user: "{{ global_user }}"
      ipa_pass: "{{ global_pass }}"
      validate_certs: no
      user: "{{ users_to_add | selectattr('group','equalto',item) | map(attribute='username') | list }}"
    with_items: "{{ users_to_add | map(attribute='group') | list | unique }}"
```